React-bootstrap: WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/SSRProvider.mjs
I have been working with React-bootstrap for more than a year but recently found this problem: whenever importing a react-bootstrap component, there will be a warning with react-aria (which is a dependency of restart/ui, and restart/ui is a dependency of react-bootstrap):
WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-aria/ssr/dist/SSRProvider.mjs
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'my-root-directory\node_modules@react-aria\ssr\dist\SSRProvider.mjs.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'my-root-directory\node_modules@react-aria\ssr\dist\SSRProvider.mjs.map'
This warning shouldn’t affect the runtime of my application, as source maps are primarily used for debugging purposes, but it still pretty annoying. Im using the latest react-bootstrap version: 2.10.2. Is this a new bug and how to solve it?
I have search for issues in both react-bootstrap, restart/ui and react-aria github page, but there is no issue mentioning this

I am also experiencing similar problem
Do you think there might be a problem with the import in my case? Did you disassemble the structure and import it?
If so, I think it will be processed by writing it line by line using the import method provided on the React-bootstrap homepage.
I hope you try one more time
// import {Button, Navbar, Container, Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'


this is not working for me. any other way?

The issue with @react-aria/ssr and Bootstrap is related to the way Bootstrap components are imported in your React application. The error you're encountering is likely caused by a mismatch between the Bootstrap version used in your project and the version supported by @react-aria/ssr.
//import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

Try this.
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'

